# ASP.Net MVC 4 Custom Validation attribute isValid is called twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a sample validation attribute to learn more about MVC. I have created the validation attribute, but when I run the application the validation attribute is called twice -> before calling the controller and before saving the DBContext. I believe this should be called only once. Can you guide me where am I doing wrong.

Validation Attribute: I am trying to validate whether the property has too many words than the specified maxWords

```
public class ValidationEx : ValidationAttribute
    {
        int _maxWords = 1;
        public ValidationEx()
            : base("{0} has more too many words")
        {
            _maxWords = 1;
        }

        public ValidationEx(int maxWords):base("{0} has more too many words")
        {
            _maxWords = maxWords;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                string data = value as string;
                if (data.Split(' ').Length > _maxWords)
                {
                    var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
                    return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
                }
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Album album)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Albums.Add(album);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.GenreID = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreID", "Name", album.GenreID);
            ViewBag.ArtistID = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistID", "ArtistName", album.ArtistID);
            return View(album);
        }
```

Note: Validation is fired before reaching controller and while executing db.SaveChanges()

Model:

```
 public class Album
    {
        public virtual int AlbumID { get; set; }
        public virtual int GenreID { get; set; }
        public virtual int ArtistID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType= typeof(ErrorMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName="TitleRequired")]
        [Display(Name="Movie Name")]
        [ValidationEx()]
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }

        [Range(0,1000)]
        public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
        public virtual string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
        public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }

        [StringLength(40)]
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

DBContext

```
public class MusicAlbumStoreDBContext : DbContext
    {
        // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        // 
        // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
        // automatically whenever you change your model schema, add the following
        // code to the Application_Start method in your Global.asax file.
        // Note: this will destroy and re-create your database with every model change.
        // 
        // System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MusicAlbumProject.Models.MusicAlbumStoreDBContext>());

        public MusicAlbumStoreDBContext() : base("name=MusicAlbumStoreDBContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Is the `validationContext` and its values the same in both calls?

Comment: I think your code should work fine.

Comment: Values in both calls are the same.

Comment: I created one more Class with IValidatableObject. Even here, the method Validate is called twice -> Before calling the controller and on db.SaveChanges(). I have added the DBContext as well for your reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the same class as model and as view model. There is a reason why MVC distringuishes between these 2 types. You really should add a separate model and a separate view model class.

`IsValid()` is called twice

1. before the controller action as the data is validated before the action is called
2. on `db.SaveChanges()` because the DB Context also does a validation

Comment: Validate method is called twice because Entity Framework also will validate before saving the content to the database http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/validate-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx.